# mathematical operations on a numpy array with NaNs

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any way to ignore NaNs in a numpy array?
My problem is that I have a numpy array with few NaNs and I am doing a mathematical operation on the array, such as

```
dev0 = numpy.sqrt((x0 - x1) ** 2 + (y0 - y1) ** 2)
```

Ofcourse, because of the NaN, there is an exception. `TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S14') dtype('S14') dtype('S14')`

So, is there any way, that the above operation is successful the NaNs, yet the array dev0 size is the same as x0.

Edit, after few comments below:

This is a YAML file where I am reading from.

```
- { x: 5.4725573730468750e+02, y: -3.4774234008789062e+02 }
- { x: 3.8519703125000000e+04, y: 6.4700851440429688e+01 }
- { x: 5.8734118652343750e+02, y: -3.4341723632812500e+02 }
- { x: 8.8773913574218750e+02, y: -3.4931005859375000e+02 }
- { x: 4.0723339843750000e+02, y: -3.4757397460937500e+02 }
- { x: NaN, y: -65535. }
```

Code-

```
    collision_points = yaml_load["points"]
    # the entries in collision_points are not read as strings
    collision = list()
    for count in range(len(collision_points)):
        xy = list()
        xy.append(collision_points[count]["x"])
        xy.append(collision_points[count]["y"])
        collision.append(xy)
    data = numpy.array(collision)
    x0, y0 = data.T
    # x1, y1 comes from somewhere else. Its also a numpy array
    dev0 = numpy.sqrt((x0 - x1) ** 2 + (y0 - y1) ** 2)
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen to the NaN elements?

Comment: a gap. whereever there is a Nan, dev0 also has a NaN

Comment: Not sure I follow, despite the NaNs, your shapes should be preserved.

Comment: What error are you getting? `np.sqrt` works fine with NaNs.

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S14') dtype('S14') dtype('S14') - Python 2.7

Comment: By default, numpy will propagate NaNs quietly. If you've configured it to instead signal on NaNs, just don't do that.

Comment: that has nothing to do with NaNs, why are you performing arithmetic with strings?

Comment: Have you maybe written the output out as a string and then tried to read it back with `eval` and ended up with something like `np.array([1, 3, 'nan', 5])` instead of `np.array([1, 3, np.nan, 5])`? If so… don't do that, either.

Comment: let me have a look again. brb.

Comment: @abarnert i have updated the post.. you may be right, that the NaN is a string after I read from the yaml file..So, how do I change it to an integer type?

Comment: First, NaN is only for floats, not ints. But since all but the last row in your YAML have floats anyway, that seems like an even bigger problem. Second, you need to show us the code that reads this YAML and generates an array out of it before we can debug it for you.

Comment: You should be able to do something like `ns = numpy.nansum ; dev0 = numpy.sqrt((ns(x0) - ns(x1)) ** 2 + (ns(y0) - ns(y1)) ** 2)`...

Comment: Also, IIRC, the right way to write a NaN in YAML is `.nan`, with an explicit dot prefix, not `NaN`; if so, you may also need to either fix the code that generated this YAML, or run some kind of pre- or post-processor.

Comment: @abarnert updated.

Comment: You still haven't shown us the code that actually loads the YAML, only the code that uses the result of doing so. It's enough for me to make a guess at the answer, but please actually edit the question into a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Writing this as an answer, that might help others.

Kudos to @abarnert for providing important hints.

After getting hints from the comments in the question, I dug up more and found out that numpy.array was indeed returning a string of elements, if it found any non number ( like NaN or apple or anything ) in the original array returned by the yaml file. The yaml file has only floating point numbers and I was confused why there was a string operation on floats. And I found out the answer that numpy.array automatically converts a floating array into a string array, in case its find any element in the array that is not a number. But if one follows the convention and writes .nan instead of NaN in the YAML file, numpy.array would consider it as a floating point.

After changing NaN to .nan by post processing, the numpy.array retains all the floating point number and the program works as expected.

The yaml file after post processing looks like this

```
- { x: 5.4725573730468750e+02, y: -3.4774234008789062e+02 }
- { x: 3.8519703125000000e+04, y: 6.4700851440429688e+01 }
- { x: 5.8734118652343750e+02, y: -3.4341723632812500e+02 }
- { x: 8.8773913574218750e+02, y: -3.4931005859375000e+02 }
- { x: 4.0723339843750000e+02, y: -3.4757397460937500e+02 }
- { x: .nan, y: -65535. }
```